# CSS Not Applying Media Query

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-selectors, media-queries

I'm currently experiencing the following problem:

[Default CSS overwriting Media Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zojXu.png)

I'm using two CSS files being processed by GULP SASS, I've declared them in the head of the HTML like this:

[HTML Head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiWhA.png)

The code is pretty simple, I did it just so I could test things out:

On styles.scss:

```
h1 {
    color: #E5E1DD;
    font-family: 'Megrim', cursive;
    font-size: 6rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 90px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 1s ease;
}
```

And on queries.scss:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
}
```

If I use the !important declaration on the queries.scss they end up working, but I'm sure this isn't the best way to fix things.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector in your media query needs to have at least the same *specifity* in order to overwrite the preceding CSS, so it needs to be

```
.hero h1 { ... }
```

Answer (score -2):

try !important keyword after css property

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {

h1 {
    font-size: 1rem !important;
}
```